# position element at center of absolute layout in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I have a list of objects coming from api which I am showing in a ListView. For each item in the list, i am rendering an absolute layout. If the item has photo I show it full stretched so that it appear as a background image for that item in the list. Then I am rendering button with item name which i want to render right at the center of the image. I went through the docs but could not find a way to do it.

```
<ListView [items]="List">
  <StackLayout>
    <template let-item="item">
      <AbsoluteLayout  class="list-item">
        <Image src="{{item.photo}}" *ngIf="item.photo" stretch="fill">  </Image>
        <Button [text]="item.name" (tap)="onItemTap(item)"></Button>
      </AbsoluteLayout>
    </template>
  </StackLayout>    
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place a GridLayout inside the AbsoluteLayout, then place the Button which should be centered inside the GridLayout:

```
<AbsoluteLayout  class="list-item">
    <Image src="{{item.photo}}" *ngIf="item.photo" stretch="fill">  </Image>
    <GridLayout background="transparent">
        <Button [text]="item.name" (tap)="onItemTap(item)"></Button>
    </GridLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set **left** and **top** for the component inside your AbsoluteLayout.
Now if you have equal sized images the things are pretty easy - you can provide displacement from the left and from the top based on your thumbnail size. Or you can provide the left and top displacement based on code-behind calculation and some more binding
e.g.

```
  <AbsoluteLayout>
    <Image src="{{item.photo}}" *ngIf="item.photo" stretch="fill">  </Image>
    <Button text="This is Label 1" [left]="leftValueBasedOnImageSize" [top]="topValueBasedOnImageSize" ></Button>
  </AbsoluteLayout>
```

You can also set the size of your absolute layout and place your button to the center based on that dimensions.

```
  <AbsoluteLayout width="300" height="300">
    <Image src="{{item.photo}}" left="0" top="0" width="300" height="300" stretch="aspectFill">  </Image>
    <Button text="Button" left="120" top="130" height="40" [left]="leftValue" [top]="topValue" ></Button>
  </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: how do you calculate the view width/height?

Answer (score 0):

try this nativescript also accept percentage value

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
  <Image src="your-image-here.jpg" width="100%" height="220"></Image>
  <GridLayout top="50%" left="50%" width="100%">
    <Label text="Lorem Ipsum" textWrap="true">
 </GridLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```